# Iterating through dimensional JSON array with jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

This may be more of an advice/best practice question, but I am wondering what the smoothest/most elegant/readable way to loop through a very large JSON array is.

Here is an example of the array. Note that sometimes the array sizes are different (as it is a DB query).

```
{
 "1":
  {
   "attributes":
    {"Label" : "Some Label"},
   "leader":
    {"123" :
       {"Name" : "Joe",
        "Age"  : "50"}
    }
 }
},
 "2"
  {"attributes":
    {"Label" : "Some label"},
  "leader":
    {"456" :
      {"Name" : "Bob",
       "Age" : "24",
       "followers" : 
          {"243" :
            {"Name" : Jimmy"}

...etc
```

In English for this example, you might get a list of Organisations that has a Leader that might have Followers that might have Employees that might have Contracts... etc .

I've actually had *no problem* iterating through this kind of structure (because I do actually know for sure what the deepest level is) by using a structure like this:

```
$.each(data, function(i, Org){
   var org = i;
  $.each(org, function (i, leader){
    $.each(leader, function (i, follower){
     .....etc
   }
 }
}
```

Is the only way to go through multi-dim arrays with nested $.each loops or is there a nicer cleaner way to achieve this, ie a recursive array (that will somehow know to move back up an index and dig through that one until theres nothing left, move back up etc.)

Comment: use a recursive function to iterate through a recursive data structure.

Comment: The answer is really going to depend on your intended use. Do you need to iterate just through the leaf nodes, or do you need to know the values in the path to the node as well? Are you moving things into a new data structure, or operating on the leaf nodes as you read them?

Comment: You might be interested in the Flatten operator provided in the Protovis library: https://github.com/mbostock/protovis/blob/master/src/data/Flatten.js

Comment: @nrabinowitz All values are important to me, because I want to build this into a table and the relationships are imperative. IE as a table, Followers need to appear after Leaders, etc. I was thinking to have each table row as an object and use the data to populate the object because some rows will appear differently than others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a recursive function I wrote sometime back that parses arrays -

```
function arrayParse(currentObject, key) {
    for (var property in currentObject) {
        if (typeof currentObject[property] === "object") {
            arrayParse(currentObject[property], property);
        } else {
            $('#result').append(
                (property=='value' && key ? key : property)
                + ' -- ' + currentObject[property] + '<br />'
            );
        }
    }
}
```

After fixing the problems with your sample array I get the following output -

```
Label -- Some Label
Name -- Joe
Age -- 50
Label -- Some label
Name -- Bob
Age -- 24
Name -- Jimmy
Age -- 40
```

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/rrtj3gbv/)

Comment: I don't understand one thing: When it finds that the currentObject is not an object, and appends it, wouldn't it start appending things backwards? IE it will append the last child before the parent?

Comment: Appending places items as the 'last' thing in the container. Prepending would change the order.

Comment: But you're appending the deepest element first, aren't you? You're saying dig through to the bottom until there's nothing to iterate, then append it. Which would mean the deepest element would be appended before the parent

Comment: No, it takes the first item that is not an object, then spits it out. Then it spits out each subsequent non-object until it has gone through the whole array. It starts the object from the top.